# Cmd - get variable in variable name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, set

I have a problem about `variable in variable` ( the code is below ) :

```
set a=1
set b=a
echo %%b%%
```

The expected result is :

```
1
```

As `a` is assigned to variable `b` and `1` is assigned to variable `a`.

Also, there is another situation :

```
set b=a
set a1=100
set c=1
call set d=%a%c%%
echo %d%
```

I want the program to first turn `%c%` to `1` and then turn `%a1%` to `100`.
The expected output is `100`.

What is the simplest way to complete this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set a=1
set b=a
call echo %%%b%%%
```

And this will work faster:

```
@echo off
set a=1
set b=a
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%b%!
endlocal
```

And just in case you need to do this within brackets context (e.g. `if` , `for` ...) :

```
@echo off
set a=1
set b=a
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
 for /f %%v in ("%b%") do echo !%%~v!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: How can I assign the value `%%%b%%%` to a variable? e.g. `set c=%%%b%%%`

Comment: again with `call set`

Answer (score 1):

like for the variable x%abc%,

```
echo x%abc%>a.a
set /p temp=<a.a
call echo %%temp%%>a.a
set /p temp=<a.a
set temp
```

That's all!