# How to return the value of a increasing variable in Batch file?

Tags: batch-file

As you can see in my script bellow, the %pin%count%% (maybe obviously for some of you) won't return the wanted value but the string value of the wanted variable, as %pin5% for instance.

I've created a script where the number of variables will depend on how many colors the user chose for his pins. The troubling part of the script is:

```
Echo - Please type the colors of the pins allowed in the purchase, 
or type dot (.) to finish this part of the script.
set count=0
:Pin
set /a count=%count%+1
set /p pin%count%=
if not %pin%count%%=="." goto Pin
```

I cannot use the IF statement because %pin%count%% returns %pin1% or %pin2% but not the value itself, how to solve this?

It seems like a simple enough syntax problem, but i'm trying everything and haven't managed to solve it yet and asking may be the fastest solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmd - get variable in variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278968/cmd-get-variable-in-variable-name)

Comment: The technicall term for your variables is _array_ and a description of its use is given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to evaluate a composite variable name, you have to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` so you can specify `!` as an extra delimiter,

The other problem you had is that you compared the variable with `"."`. Batch does not remove quotes like bash does. Don't put the quotes, or put some quotes on the left end too.

Fixed code:

```
@echo off
Echo - Please type the colors of the pins allowed in the purchase, 
echo or type dot (.) to finish this part of the script.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
:Pin
set /a count+=1
set /p pin%count%=
rem echo the variable for debug purposes
echo pin%count% = !pin%count%!
rem here's the tricky line
if not !pin%count%!==. goto Pin
```